# load a html file in a particular div from attribute href in a anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

**Div in HTML file**

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="info">Please choose a category</p>
</div>
```

**anchor tag with href attribute**

```
<a class="menu__link" href="{% url 'Profile' %}">Profile</a>
```

**My javascript function**

```
 var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');

            function loadDummyData(ev, itemName) {
                ev.preventDefault();

                closeMenu();

                gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
                classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
                    gridWrapper.innerHTML = $(".menu__link--current").attr("href")
                    console.log($(".menu__link--current").attr("href"))
                }, 500);
            }
```

**Output in console is showing the path of the url**

```
/Accounts/profile
```

If the `ev.preventDefault();` is removed, and commenting the line`gridWrapper.innerHTML = $(".menu__link--current").attr("href")`, the html page gets loaded but not in the particular content div.

The problem is i want to load that particular html page with href attribute in content div.
Any Help will be much appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to insert the tag inside the content div?

Comment: No. The href attribute in the anchor tag is a HTML page. I want to load that HTML page in the content div. @Mr Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant load external html with `InnerHTML`. [InnerHTMl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is used to insert the HTML elements into the document or targeted div. To load an external Html file, you have to use [`.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');
function loadDummyData(ev, itemName) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    closeMenu();

    gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
    classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
      classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content--loading'); 

      let path = $(".menu__link").attr("href") //Fetch path to the file
      console.log($(".menu__link").attr("href")) //Path has to be /file/filename.html
      $('.content').load(path); //========> use the path in the load method inside content div.
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: It prints out an error in the console. TypeError: gridWrapper.load is not a function.